# How can i show beauty url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm using MVC with PHP and, for example, I have this URL:

```
domain.com/{modue}/{action}
```

This will make it look like:

```
domain.com/user/join
```

I want it to show

```
domain.com/join
```

instead.

Can anyone help me?

I tried this with an .htaccess file, but I couldn't. This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ ./controller.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)/$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)$ /controller.php?modulo=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)/$ /$1/$2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)$ ./controller.php?modulo=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: If you remove the module from the URL, how is your controller going to know what module to use? (Or do you only ever have 1 module called "user"?)

Comment: have more that 1 module. mi controller:  http://pastebin.com/fEgBLWF8

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have just one controller -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```